# Rails Routes Undefined Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

My view is showing a method error:

> Error:

```
NoMethodError in AdminsBackoffice::Administradores#edit
Showing C:/projetos/iRespostas/app/views/admins_backoffice/administradores/edit.html.erb where line #5 raised:

undefined method `admins_backoffice_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000000105edf70>:0x0000000011bc8728>
Did you mean?  admins_backoffice_welcome_index_path
Extracted source (around line #5):
             
</div>

<%= form_with(model: [ :admins_backoffice, @admin ], local: true) do |form| %>
    <div class="form-group">
        <%= form.label :email %>
        <%= form.text_field :email, class:"form-control", placeholder:"Email do administrador" %>
```

My view code:

> edit.html.erb

```
<div class="d-sm-flex align-items-center justify-content-between mb-4">
   <h1 class="h3 mb-0 text-gray-800">Editar Administrador</h1>
</div>

<%= form_with(admin: [ :admins_backoffice, @admin ], local: true) do |form| %>
    <div class="form-group">
        <%= form.label :email %>
        <%= form.text_field :email, class:"form-control", placeholder:"Email do administrador" %>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
        <%= form.label :password %>
        <%= form.password_field :password, class:"form-control", placeholder:"Senha" %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <%= form.label :password_confirmation %>
        <%= form.password_field :password_confirmation, class:"form-control", placeholder:"Confirmação da senha" %>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Salvar</button>
<% end %>
```

My controller code:

> administradores_controller.rb

```
class AdminsBackoffice::AdministradoresController < AdminsBackofficeController
  #efore_action :set_admin, only: [:show, :edit, :update]
  
  def index
    @admins = Admin.all
  end

  def show
    #
  end

  def edit
    #
  end

  def update
    #
  end


  private
    def set_admin
      @admin = Admin.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

My routes:

> routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :users_backoffice do
    get 'welcome/index'
  end

  namespace :site do
    get 'home/index'
  end

  namespace :admins_backoffice do
    get 'welcome/index' # Dashboard 
    resources :administradores, only: [:index, :edit, :update] # Administradores Controller CRUD
  end

  devise_for :users
  devise_for :admins

  root 'site/home#index'
end
```

When i change the `model` of `form_with(model: [ :admins_backoffice, @admin ], local: true)`, the page loads normally, but the form's href is on the same link as the edit route, which doesn't work.

```
<form action="/admins_backoffice/administradores/19/edit" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

When trying to use `form_with(model: ...)`, you have to be careful to have followed the Rails conventions on model naming or the methodology may not work properly.

In the case of your code, you have a concept of `Administradores` that's backed up by a Model with a different name - `Admin`. As such, Rails is having trouble resolving the connection between the two in generating the route from the model.

In essence, Rails asks your `@admin` object what it's model name is and it responds with `Admin`, but none of your routes would resolve to an `admin` route.

To get the connection you want between `Administradores` and `Admin`, you'll need to manually override the model name in your `models/admin.rb` definition:

```rb
class Admin < ApplicationRecord
  ...

  def self.model_name
    ActiveModel::Name.new(self, nil, "Administradore")
  end

  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't agree that you need to patch your admin class.
You can just specify option `url` in your `form_with`

```rb
<%= form_with(admin: [ :admins_backoffice, @admin ], local: true, url: admins_backoffice_administradore_path(@admin)) do |form| %>
```